# Ubuntu doesn't output video after switching into graphics mode

Tags: boot, graphics, monitor

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 machine. Until yesterday, it booted up like normal, but this morning, it tried to boot, but didn't output any video. On boot, the UEFI setup works just fine, a snipped from the console shows up and then it doesn't output anything. There is no "No Signal" error, it's just a black output.

A family member suggested, that it stops outputing after it switched from terminal mode into graphics mode, which would explain why there was still a brief booting message at the start.

Ctrl+Alt+F1 - Ctrl+Alt+F12 did nothing and the off-button only works when pressed long enough (no controlled shutdown). It seems that the computer is doing something, since the fan speed is increasing/decreasing every now and then.

System Specs:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Intel i5 with graphics module
- 16GB RAM
- nvidia Geforce RTX 3060

Comment: use ctrl-alt-f3 to reach a terminal

Comment: @Esther Sorry, I only wrote Alt+, but I meant Ctrl+Alt+. That didn't work.